# How to make this code work to remove elements stored in "str"? It works fine untill two elements which needs to be removed are stored consecutively

Tags: python

```
enter code here
```

import sys

j=['b','b','b','t','b','b']

print('Initial List:',j)

leng=len(j)

ind=None

str='b'

try:

```
 ind=j.index(str)
```

except ValueError:

```
 print("List does not contain value")
```

print("First occurence is at index number:",ind)

j.pop(ind) #to remove the first occurence

print("Item Removed at Index no:",ind,"Updated List:",j)

if ind<=0:

```
    while ind<=leng:


        ind+=1 


        try:

              if j[ind]==str:

               ind=j.index(str,ind,leng)

               print('Another occurence is at index number:',ind)

               j.pop(ind)

               print("Item Removed at index no:",ind,"Updated List:",j)

              
        except ValueError:

            print("List scanned, The frequency of the element is 1")

        except IndexError:

            print("Index out of Range")
```

print("Final List",j)

Comment: Please edit your question, and do some formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below logic to remove elements from a list that matches with str.

```
j=['b','b','b','t','b','b']
str = 'b'
newlist = []

for s in j:
 if s not in newlist:
  newlist.append(s)

print(newlist)
```

OR you can use set predefined Data type to remove duplicate elements.

```
newlistset = set(j)
print(newlistset)
```

Your logic is not working because you are removing item from the origin list and every pop method calls reduce length of list that's why you are getting IndexError.

Comment: this ain't working man, reply with  full code

Comment: I have modified my code. Try with my new code.